# can a node be a part of multiple chef environments

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chefdk

Is it possible for a server to be a part of multiple environments in the same organization? If so, how do we add the node to a new environment without overriding the existing one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, one to one mapping. You can have multiple roles in the run list though.